# Symfony Doctrine_Query DELETE with INNER JOIN

Tags: doctrine, symfony1, inner-join, sql-delete

I am using symfony+doctrine, and I want to perform a delete query with a join. See below for my code I am currently using that works fine.

```
$sql = 'DELETE a
 FROM a
 INNER JOIN b ON a.b_id = b.id
 WHERE b.c_id = :c_id';

$pdo = Doctrine_Manager::getInstance()->getCurrentConnection()->getDbh();
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$params = array('c_id' => $c_id);
$stmt->execute($params);
```

Anyone know how I can do this using:

```
Doctrine_Core::getTable('a')
```

Or

```
Doctrine_Query::create()->delete()->from('a')
```

I have had no luck with either.

I just don't really want to use raw SQL in my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do it

```
Doctrine_Query::create()
    ->delete('a a')
    ->innerJoin('a.b b')
    ->where('b.c_id = ?', $c_id)
    ->execute()
```

Comment: thanks but I'm still having no luck. maybe I'm doing something wrong in my query formation, but I use Doctrine_Query a lot, so I don't think so: Syntax error or access violation ... Doctrine_Connection->exec('DELETE FROM player_card INNER JOIN player p2 ON p.player_id = p2.id WHERE (game_id = ?)', array('21'))

Comment: actually you know I don't even really care that much about this, so I'm just going to use my original raw SQL.

Comment: dql delete & update don't support joins (http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#delete-queries)